# Displaying linked list nodes vertically and horizontally in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, cout

before asking the following question, I really did my best for 4 hours to look for an answer but unfortunately I did not found what I am looking for in C++. Hopefully, some of you could help me. The question is very simple. I have a linked list whose nodes take 2 key values for example :

```
struct myNode{
  int a ;
  int b ;
  myNode *nextNode ;
  myNode *prevNode ;
} ;
```

I can display all nodes of such a list vertically using  COUT such as (pseudo code) :

```
while (myList){
  cout << myList->a << " " << myList->b << "\n" ;
  increment myList (myList = myList->nextNode) ;
}
```

the result will be :

```
 a1 b1
 a2 b2
 a3 b3
 .
 .
 .
 an bn
```

Instead of displaying this vertically I want to display them horizontally to have a result similar to :

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 ... an
b1 b2 b3 b4 ... bn
```

In other words, how can I print in C++ a number of n elements vertically and then move to the right and start printing other n elements vertically (from the first line) parallel to the previous column and so on...

Thank you for your answers.

L.

Comment: You can first put the values into a 2 *n matrix, then print the matrix in row-order

Comment: @taocp : Thnaks. To optimize execution time I would rather prefer not to do this (I already thought about this solution). I am wondering if there are COUT or IOSTREAM option to do it directly.

Answer (score 0):

To jump a line back in the console needs OS specific methods and is not recommended in this case. The easiest way I can think of is to use two loops, like this:

```
while (myList)
{
    cout << myList->a << " ";
    increment myList (myList = myList->nextNode);
}
cout << "\n";
// set myList to begin
while (myList)
{
    cout << myList->b << " ";
    increment myList (myList = myList->nextNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see the problem. E.g.

```
int const n = blahblah;

for( auto p = myList; p != nullptr; p = p->nextNode )
{
   cout << setw( n ) << p->a;
}
cout << endl;

for( auto p = myList; p != nullptr; p = p->nextNode )
{
   cout << setw( n ) << p->b;
}
cout << endl;
```

---

**UPDATE**.

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020146/displaying-linked-list-nodes-vertically-and-horizontally-in-c/26020862?noredirect=1#comment40805746_26020862) the OP has explained what he perceives to be a problem with the above:

> **“** If we use the solution proposed above, we will need to write a For or While loop for every single key value of the list.

The code duplication is very easily – trivially – remedied by *naming* and *parameterizing* the sequence output operation, e.g.

```
template< class Pointer, class MemberPointer >
void display_value_sequence( Pointer const my_list, MemberPointer const m )
{
    int const n = blahblah;

    for( auto p = my_list; p != nullptr; p = p->nextNode )
    {
        cout << setw( n ) << p->*m;
    }
}

void foo()
{
    // ...
    using Node = decltype( *myList );
    display_value_sequence( myList, &Node::a );   cout << endl;
    display_value_sequence( myList, &Node::b );   cout << endl;
}
```

One might abstract away on this, e.g. some function returning a `vector<string>` of string representations of items, and so on, but I think that would be premature.

Disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I think I may not have presented the problem correctly. The solutions you proposed are already known to me. I want to avoid browsing into the list twice (what if the list contains more key values ?). I am looking for a solution that does not require to surf the list as many times as it has key values. Thanks again.

Comment: re "what if the list contains more key values ?", I ***really*** fail to see the problem.

Comment: If we use the solution proposed above, we will need to write a For or While loop for every single key value of the list. The difficulty, in having a considerable number of key values (say 100) is that we will have to write a 100 For/While loops. Anyways... what I asked seems to be not possible to do. Thanks again guys !

Comment: @Alf I forgot this : In addition to the difficulty in writing the code the big problem is that the program will not be optimal (reading the key values separately).

Comment: @Iounice: the concern about efficiency is misguided. the only way to know which is more or less efficient is to **MEASURE**, for the relevant computers and data and work load. not doing that, but investing effort to optimize in a way that one for no good reason think will work, is called *premature optimization*, and was famously characterized as Evil by Donald Knuth, and many others.